# How to use Indexes access operator (get & set) for Arrays?

Tags: android, kotlin, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to use the **Indexed access operator** as it explained in the following link:
[Indexed access operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html)

It is written there that it works exactly as **set & get** but code isn't compiled when trying for example to compile the following:

```
   var vv : Array<Int> = Array(6 ,{ 5*it })

vv[1, 4] =5
```

that is exactly like the pattern in the link:

> a[i, j] = b   a.set(i, j, b)

After reading comments I understand that a[i,j] means setting a value to two dimensional array, but still the following code doesn't work:

```
  val rows = 3
val cols = 4
var arr = Array(rows) {  IntArray(cols) }
arr[2,3] = 5
```

Comment: An array is one-dimensional, so there should only be one parameter for the indexed access operator. What would you expect 4 to represent in your example above?

Comment: @Tenfour04,I thought it put in the places: 1 & 4 the value:5 Now that I understand that it means a[1][4] = 5 (java syntax). But now when i understand that it mean a two dimensional array my code still doesn't work (i added an example to my post)

Comment: For some reason they didn’t include functions for using the 2D syntax. You have two use `[1, 4]`. But I think you could write an extension function to enable it. Like `operator fun <T> Array<Array<T>>.set...`

Comment: What  do you mean when saying *You have two use [1, 4]*?
What is written in the link isn't right?

Comment: I meant `[1][4]`, sorry.

Comment: @Tenfour04, Ok thank you